# db2 : How to convert timestamp to minute in db2

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, db2, minute

I need a help. How to convert timestamp to minute in sql query? Really appreciate it. Below are my table.
[Here is my timestamp table field. Need to convert it in minute to get time duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpxg5.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATEPART(mi, changedate) AS minute from Table_01
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer but error. It say mi is invalid. any solution?

Comment: Please specify the SQL Server version you are using and also you can use n instead of mi as it gives proper output with sql server 2016

Comment: Actually I'm using db2 sir.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "convert"?
It is always helpful to give an example.

There are lots of functions in Db2 - very helpful new ones in Db2 11.1 - check out (depending on your goal):

- date_trunc ('minutes', current timestamp) as minutes
- date_part('minutes', current timestamp) as date_part_minutes
- minutes_between('01.03.2016', '01.01.1970') as minutes_between

Comment: I need output for duration in minute. For example my data timestamp column 1 is 2018-01-12-19.44.33.336000 and column 2 is 2018-01-12-11.54.33.042000. So i need to subtract between 2 timestamp and need in minute format. Please guide me. Really appreciate it sir.

Comment: SELECT ((SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE) FROM WOSTATUS WHERE WOSTATUS.STATUS = 'COMP' AND WONUM=WORKORDER.WONUM) - 
(SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE) FROM WOSTATUS WHERE WOSTATUS.STATUS = 'ACCEPT' AND WONUM=WORKORDER.WONUM)) AS WORKDURATION - currently that is my query. I get the ouput but in Hour. I need the duration in minute for total working. I appreciate your help sir. Kindly Regards.

Comment: What other date/time related columns are in table WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE?  Your code is *only* selecting the HOUR column . Does that mean an hour number between 0 and 23 ?  Don't you want a *time* that means the HOUR and MINUTE?  If you have a TIMESTAMP datatype column in WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE then you can use TIMESTAMPDIFF function with first parameter=4 (for minutes) to get duration by subtracting the two timestamp values.

Comment: My code is wrong because I dont know how to get duration minute by subtracting 2 timestamp. Can you give me some example please sir? Is it like this sir :- SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF((SELECT WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE FROM WOSTATUS WHERE WOSTATUS.STATUS = 'COMPLETE' AND WONUM='1018' )-
(SELECT WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE FROM WOSTATUS WHERE WOSTATUS.STATUS = 'ACCEPT' AND WONUM='1018'),MINUTE) AS DURATION 
FROM WOSTATUS
?

Comment: Show the  Db2datatype name of WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE .

Comment: WOSTATUS.CHANGEDATE datatype is timestamp. WOSTATUS.STATUS is varchar. Need to subtract WOSTATUS.STATUS(complete - accept). The id is WONUM from other table which is join with WOSTATUS table. So one id have 2 data timestamp which is complete and accept, need to subtract to get the duration of work in minute. I do not want to access the timestamp field directly but i need to be able to capture the work duration just by referring to wonum. Really Appreciate your help sir. Kind regards.

Comment: Use minutes_between like this:select minutes_between(current timestamp, current timestamp + 1 day) from sysibm.sysdummy1

1
--------------------
               -1440

  1 record(s) selected.